# Alignment changes partway through enumerate item

Tags: vertical-alignment, enumerate, layout

I'm creating a set of questions and halfway through one of my questions the alignment changes - you can see in the picture how the alignment changes for question 4b.  I've not had this issue before and haven't managed to fix it!  Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: it's very hard to debug a screenshot, please post a small complete document that has the problem as a code block (`{}` button) in your question.

Comment: unrelated but  use `\cos` not `cos` (you show both above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never ignore errors (note the red 6 in your screenshot) you have a `$` missing at the end of line 33.

TeX makes no attempt to make sensible output after an error the output is at best useful for debugging.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I hadn't even noticed the little red error mark, but will look out for them in future!

Comment: @jemima there are two in your screenshot, the one on the right with the total error count (not a meaningful number usually as one error can generate multiple spurious later errors) and one on the left highlighting the line 34 where the error is reported